# Django admin, static files use wrong directory

Tags: django, settings

I am using django 1.4, and when I have this in settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/_s/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('admin', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin'),
)
```

And then access `/_s/admin/css/base.css` Django tries to load it from a different path and writes:

```
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/css/base.css" does not exist
```

Why does this happens?

**UPD**
I use `./manage.py runcserver 0.0.0.0:8001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in

```
./manage.py runcserver 0.0.0.0:8001
```

I used concurrent server, not default django debug server (I thought they both work in the same way (except threads))

But it is not true =(

**UPD**
From 1.4 you can use django debug server, it is multithreaded by default.

Comment: Note that in Django 1.4, [the default dev server is multithreaded by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#development-server-multithreading). Depending on your requirements, you might not need to use `runcserver` any more.

Answer (score 2):

The `STATICFILES_DIRS` is used for collecting static files, `./manage.py collectstatic`.  It tell Django which folders to look in in order to pull all static files together in to one place.

When serving up static files Django will only look in `STATIC_ROOT`.

[Official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-dirs)

Comment: If I change STATIC_ROOT nothing changes! It just continues using different path, should I use collectstatic on debug server? I just want to set different path.

Comment: How are you hosting your project?  runserver, apache etc

Comment: Hmm ok, runserver should find it.  Does `base.css` actually exist there?

Comment: Ofcourse I checked the path I wrote. The problem is django uses different path!